# Call to undefined function random_bytes() on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

After deploying codeignter project i encountered a problem with forgot password implementation via email. Though, on local host it worked fine. 
I get an error :
Message: Call to undefined function random_bytes()
Here is my **controller function** function

```
public function forgotPassword () {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email", "trim|required");
        if($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->load->view('forgotPassword');
        }else {
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $user=$this->db->get_where('users', array('email'=>$email, 'is_active'=>1))->row_array();
            if($user) {
                $token = base64_encode(random_bytes(32));
                $user_token=array(
                    'email'=>$email,
                    'token'=>$token,
                    'date_created'=>time()
                );
                $this->db->insert('user_token', $user_token);
                $this->load->model('Register_model', 'reg');
                $this->reg->sendEmail($token, 'forgot');
                $this->session->set_flashdata("message", "Check your email to reset your password");
                redirect("auth/forgotPassword");

            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata("message", "Email doesn't exist or is not activated");
                redirect("auth/forgotPassword");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Model function***

```
public function sendEmail($token, $type) {
        $config = array(
            'protocol'=>'smtp',
            'smtp_host'=>'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_user'=>'***',
            'smtp_pass'=>'***',
            'smtp_port'=> '465',
            'mailtype'=> 'html',
            'charset'=> 'iso-8859-1',
            'newline' =>"\r\n",
            'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->from('***', 'Web app');
        $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
        if($type == 'verify') {
            $this->email->subject('Account verification');
            $this->email->message('Click here to verify account: <a href="' .
                base_url() . 'index.php/auth/verify?email=' . $this->input->post('email') .
                '&token=' . urlencode($token) . '">Activate</a>');
        }
        elseif ($type == 'forgot') {
            $this->email->subject('Reset password');
            $this->email->message('Click here to reset your password: <a href="' .
                base_url() . 'index.php/auth/resetpassword?email=' . $this->input->post('email') .
                '&token=' . urlencode($token) . '">Reset</a>');
        }

        //$this->email->send();
        if($this->email->send()) {
            return true;
        }else {
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
            die;
        }


    }
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using on the server? `random_bytes` was introduced in PHP7.

Comment: i'm new to codeigniter and that was my first deployments. i assume i can check the php version in app.yaml? it says " runtime: php55
api_version: 1"

Comment: No, the PHP version is the environment on the server, not in your code. You can check it by creating a file on the server with the contents `<?php phpinfo();` and browsing to that. You can also try on the command line with `php -v`, but the command line and web versions may not always match up.

Comment: yhank for your help. i entred php -v in google shell. it says PHP 7.2.29-1+0~20200320.39+debian9~1.gbp513c2e

Comment: The first result found from a Google search for the error produced the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Check version on your local machine and remote server.
Because in documentation:

> Although this function was added to PHP in PHP 7.0, a » userland implementation is available for PHP 5.2 to 5.6, inclusive.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php

Comment: on server it says  PHP 7.2.29-1+0~20200320.39+debian9~1.gbp513c2e .....